# {PHP,PDO} Unable to show/refresh table on button press

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

I was trying to make a page for table management purposes.
So I tried to test if I can call a table to show up with a press of a button, 
if I can achieve that, I maybe can use it as a way to "refresh" the table after the user finishes his changes to the data. 
However, I'm can't get the code to work.
This is what I expect the page to function.

[Where I'm stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVcKo.png)

[What I'm hoping it'll do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP0MN.png)

These are my codes:
Alter_DB.php

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AlterData</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('div#test_table_go').load('showthetable.php', 'update=true').scrollTop(lastScrollPos);
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
<body>

Welcome!<br /> 
You are connecting to :<?php echo $_POST["dbname"]; ?><br>
<?php 

$db=$_POST["dbname"];

$table=$_POST["table"];

$spl_to_table="SELECT * FROM $db.$table;";

try {
        $dbh = new PDO(
                        "mysql:host=localhost", 
                        "root", 
                        "123"
                        );
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
        echo "Connection: Failed";
    }
    echo "Connection: Success <br> Connecting to table:".$table,"<br><br>";

echo '<form action="" method="POST"><input type="button" value="show table" name="gotable"></form>';

switch ($table){
    case 'test_table':
        echo '<div id="test_table_go"></div>';
        break;
}
    if(isset($_POST['gotable']))
{
   echo('gogo');
    refreshTable();
} 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

showthetable.php

```
<?php
$db='testdb';

$table='test_table';

$spl_to_table="SELECT * FROM $db.$table;";
try {
        $dbh = new PDO(
                        "mysql:host=localhost", 
                        "root", 
                        "123"
                        );
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
        echo "Connection: Failed";
    }
$result = $dbh->query($spl_to_table);
$q = $dbh->query("DESCRIBE $db.$table"); 
$q -> execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$sth = $dbh->query($spl_to_table);
$count = $sth->columnCount();
echo '<br><hr> 
<table border="1" style="width:100%" >';


foreach ($table_fields as $value){
        echo '<th>'.$value,'</th>';

    }


while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $i=0;
    echo '<tr>';

    while ($i<=($count-1)){
    echo '<td><center>'.$row[$i],'</center></td>';
    $i=$i+1;
    }

}
echo '</table>';



?>
```

Comment: First of all you should assign vars with PDO instead of blindly putting them in your query. Also as soon as you post `go_table` you're losing the var `$_POST['table']`.

Comment: some spaghetti code here...

Comment: A few suggestions: 1) Try using AJAX with a bit cleaner code. When I say a bit cleaner code, I mean to properly segregate your HTML, JS and PHP. 2) Try to refine your logic. This will enhance the UX as well. In case you are in agreement to these points, let me know. I might help in solving this problem.

Comment: Thx for the suggestions. First of all, yes, these codes are like a Frankenstein monster, I'm used to using a single kind of language, so when I try to use multiple languages, I sort of panicked and used everything I found in google. 
So where should I start? 
Should I start to segregate the languages, or should I just rebuild the page from scratch?